# Using SQL like operator in Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, sql-like

In a Databricks SQL notebook, the SQL like operator seems to work in a 'SHOW TABLES' statement, but not in a SELECT statement. E.g.:

```
SHOW TABLES from database like '*foo*'
```

Will return all tables containing 'foo' in the name. All good.

However:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tableName as db where db.columnName like '*bar*'
```

Returns no results (when there are definitely values that contain 'bar' in the column).

I would have expected this query to return all values in the db.columnName that contain 'bar'.

Is this a Databricks thing or am I being an idiot?

Comment: placeholders for strings are in sql `%`

Comment: Ah! Could have sworn I tried % too but yes that works now. Still doesn't quite explain why * works in the SHOW TABLES statement, but not in the SELECT statement?

Comment: show tables is working differently from SELECT. But % is defined in all databases for strings

Comment: there is a `rlike`